# Relatively low ambitious frontiers

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, soft-question, quantum-computing

What are some of the current "relatively" low ambitious frontiers for MA/PhD thesis in complexity theory class separations/containment or quantum computing?

For example: In the draft version of Arora & Barak's book, it is mentioned that:
**Frontier 2.1: Exhibit a language in NEXP that is not in ACC0 (6)**
This was solved by Williams soon after that.

Comment: I believe Ryan mentioned in an interview that he worked on that despite his advisor's opinion. In any case, focusing a PhD on 60 year old open questions can be very risky.

Comment: I wouldn't do anything in quantum computing until "quantum supremacy" has been proven. If Levin-Goldreich-Kalai are correct, there are going to be a lot of people with Egg-On-Face !